# find line index in a text file python

Tags: python, search, indexing, line

I want to get the index of the line that corresponds to a certain string (in this case, InChI=1S/C11etc..) in a text file (content), here is my code:

```
with open('compounds.dat', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    index = [x for x in range(len(content)) if "InChI=1S/C11H8O3/c1-6-5-9(13)10-7(11(6)14)3-2-4-8(10)12/h2-5" in content[x].lower()]
    print(index)
```

However I get empty bracket []. But I am pretty sure that the line exist, because if I run this:

```
for line in f:
    if u"InChI=1S/C11H8O3/c1-6-5-9(13)10-7(11(6)14)3-2-4-8(10)12/h2-5" in line:
        l = line
```

I get the line I am interested.

Comment: Your pattern has upper case characters and you're lowercasing your string  `content[x].lower()` before the comparison... why?

Comment: Use regex.. if you file is not too huge, performance of Python regex is pretty good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding upon my comment, calling `lower()` will lowercase your target string, while your search string has upper case letters - there's no chance you'll match anything like that.

Additionally, you don't have to iterate over the range. `for` can directly iterate over the items in `content`. This will work.

```
search_str = "InChI=1S/C11H8O3/c1-6-5-9(13)10-7(11(6)14)3-2-4-8(10)12/h2-5"
lines = [x for x in content if search_str in content]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `.lower()` in the code and it should work fine.